# mongoose find date using $gte and $lte for today?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
date_range: {
   from: 2020-08-08T14:46:43.171+00:00
   to: 2020-08-08T14:46:43.171+00:00
}
```

Today is 8/8/2020, so I have the above data in my mongodb collection but when I try to use this query it doesn't match

```
MyModel.find({
 date_range: {
  from: { $gte: new Date() },
  to: { $lte: new Date() },
 }
})
```

any clue why it doesn't match?

Answer (score 2):

> any clue why it doesn't match

Let's say current time is 14:00:00. Then `lte` condition fails.

`14:46:43`(toDate) is not lesser than `14:00:00`

Let's say current time is `16:00:00`. Then `gte` condition fails.

`14.46:43`(fromDate) is not greater than `16:00:00`

Because condition is `AND` in the query.

You could use the below:

```
db.collectionName.find({
  "$or": [ //OR condition
    {
      date_range: {
        from: {
          $gte: new Date()
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "date_range.to": {
        $lte: new Date()
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

**OR**

If you have to find your data falls in current day, use @frozen's answer which is `start time - 00:00:00` and end time is `23:59:59.999`

Use startTime in `gte` and end time in `lte`

Answer (score 1):

`new Date()` returns the current time in milliseconds, if you're trying to match all dates for today, you need to have `$gte: <start-of-today>` and `$lte: <end-of-today>`.